# I want the user to enter text in a text box, how can i do this?

Tags: processing

I want the user to enter text in a text box (such as a login text box on some site).

I tried to search in `text()` bibliography and other similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

This guy seems to have figured it out: http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/. Look for the textArea control.

If you don't like this, I read that the g4p library had something like an inputbox. Otherwise you will have to draw it yourself (which would be a nice exercise) using keyboard inputs and the like.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called a graphical user interface, or [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). There are many ways to approach this problem:

1. Code it yourself. Use something like the `rect()` function to draw a text box, and the `keyPressed()` function to detect key presses.
2. Use a library. The [Processing libraries](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/#gui) page lists several GUI libraries. Try each of them out and see which one you like best.
3. Use a more general GUI library. If you're deploying as Java, then you might use Swing or JavaFX. If you're deploying as JavaScript, then you might use HTML elements.

Any of the above might work, and which approach you choose depends more on you, your context, and your preferences. We can't tell you which is best, because it's all up to what you prefer.